# How to seperate a vertex?

Tags: shortcut

There was a shortcut for seperating a vertex without "P".
You selected the vertex and when you , it got loose, seperating one face from another.

What is this operation is called, what is it's shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

Found it, Press "V" to detach edges or vertices. This does not kick the selected parts outside the present mesh like Seperate("P") does.

It's edge seperation.